# In Swift, how do I prevent a function from being called on a subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have a base class that stores a lot of other data objects within some data structures, and this class manages those data objects in my collections through a group of `add`/`remove` functions that keep my data structures in sync.

Now I go to subclass this base class, and the subclass is just like the base class except that it has special rules for what kinds of data objects it will accept (it looks at the values on the data objects, and rejects them if the values aren't right). Because of this "validity" check, I created a new function just for the subclass called `change`. In the `change` function, it examines all of the incoming data objects and verifies that they are ok, and replaces all of the data objects in the data structures with these data objects.

The problem is that I don't want someone to be able to make a subclass object and allow them to call the base class `add`/`remove` functions, because I only want the subclass to be able to be changed through the subclass's `change` function.

I haven't found a good way to "disable" the use of those base class functions in the subclass. I can `override` the functions and implement empty implementations, but there's no feedback to the caller that the function didn't do anything. And if I use something like `fatalError`, it isn't compile time, it's runtime.

My other thoughts are to break the functionality of the base class into multiple protocols, and change the base class to simply have all of the data structures, but conforming to none of the protocols and then have multiple subclasses, where one that wants the `add` functionality can inherit from the base and additionally conform to the `add` protocol, but one that doesn't want `add` or `remove` can inherit from the base, and simply not conform to any of the protocols and instead create their own `change` functions to modify the data structures.

Here's a simpler hierarchy to explain:

```
class Parent {
  
  func doThis() { print("Parent Did This") }
  func doThat() { print("Parent Did That") }
  
}

class Child: Parent {
  
  override func doThis() {
    print("Child Did This")
  }
  
  // I want this to be a compile time error
  override func doThat() {
    print("Not Supported")
    return
  }
  
}
```

Is there an easier way to "hide" a function in a subclass?

## EDIT 1

To better explain my proposed solution, and whether or not there is an easier way to achieve it with my current hierarchy, here's what the hierarchy would have to look like using some protocols:

```
protocol CanDoThis {
  func doThis()
}

protocol CanDoThat {
  func doThat()
}

class Parent {
  // Important properties that all children should have
  var property1: Int = 0
  var property2: String = ""
}

class Child1: Parent, CanDoThis {
  func doThis() { print("Child1 Can Do This") }
}

class Child2: Parent, CanDoThat {
  func doThat() { print("Child2 Can Do That") }
}

class Child3: Parent, CanDoThis, CanDoThat {
  func doThis() { print("Child3 Can Do This") }
  func doThat() { print("Child3 Can Do That") }
}
```

Comment: How does this work if someone passes a Child object to a function that takes a Parent parameter?

Comment: That's part of my problem. If you do pass a Child object as a Parent parameter and try to call `doThat`, I don't know of a way to make it a compile time error. And simply leaving an empty implementation doesn't let the caller know that their call did nothing, which seems like a bad practice to me.

Comment: In EDIT 1, I explained my proposed solution using protocols, which would solve the "Child as a Parent parameter" problem, but I just didn't necessarily want to make a bunch of protocols for each piece of functionality that currently is in my rather large base class.

Comment: Your edit is not clear to me, but basing on the first example I was able to trigger a compile-time error using the "private" accessor and splitting the code in two different swift files (since private in swift works on a per-file basis). Is there any reason because you didn't use private?

Comment: @LombaX, can you explain what you mean by splitting the code into two different files? Using private in the base class would mean that no subclasses would ever get to use the function, which isn't what I want. I only want certain subclasses to never be able to invoke certain public methods from the base class. The edit was to show how using protocols for every public function, I could keep my data structures on the base class, and each kind of subclass would conform to the protocol that gives them only the functionality they want and nothing they don't want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Disclaimer

The protocol version would probably be better design - see the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) amount the other things you mentioned.

#### Answering the question

You can use the attribute `@available()` (see [Swift -> Language Reference -> Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)).

```
class Parent {
    func doThis() { print("Parent Did This") }
    func doThat() { print("Parent Did That") }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override func doThis() {
        print("Child Did This")
    }

    @available(*, unavailable, message:"Child can't doThat")
    override func doThat() {
        print("Not Supported")
    }
}


let parent = Parent()
parent.doThis()
parent.doThat()

let child = Child()
child.doThis()
child.doThat()
```

You get the following error message on `child.doThat()`:

> 'doThat()' is unavailable: Child can't doThat

However you can get around this by doing the following (again, see Liskov substitution principle):

```
let maybeChild: Parent = Child()
maybeChild.doThis()
maybeChild.doThat()
```

Comment: A combination of `available` and `final` would probably be the way to go, but the more I think about it, and with the polymorphic workaround you mention, I don't think there's a good permanent solution that doesn't involve composition with a bunch of different protocols for full customization. However, the combination of `available` and `final` certainly does answer my question, so I'll mark it.

Comment: Ouhhh this is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'd handle this using `@availability`. Something like:

```
@available(*, deprecated=1.0, message="Do not call this method")
final func foo(){ //function you want to protect
}
```

This will give you a compiler warning any time you call the function.

Interestingly, marking the function as `unavailable` will throw a compiler error, making it impossible to build the app if anyone calls this function. Unfortunately, there is no way to suppress that error in Swift, so that will break it for your good use cases as well. Maybe you can get around this by using `self.performSelector("foo")`.

Also note I marked `foo()` as `final`, which prevents it from being overridden by a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is access control. Swift's modifier for this is `internal`. [You can read more about it here in the docs under Access Control.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Comment: Internal is close, but not quite what I'm looking for. While it would prevent an outside module from using the function, it doesn't keep *ME* from being able to access a function from within my own framework. I don't want to accidentally call one of these functions from one of my subclasses, and mess up the subclass (calling `add` or `remove` instead of the `change` function messes up the subclass).

Answer (score 0):

I think the most obvious solution is this:

just set the add and remove function in the base class as private

### Example

```swift
class Parent {
  
  func doThis() { print("Parent Did This") }
  private func doThat() { print("Parent Did That") }
  
}

class Child: Parent {
  
  override func doThis() {
    print("Child Did This")
  }
  
  // This is a compile time error as the subclass will not be allowed to override this class, because it's private.
  override func doThat() {
    print("Not Supported")
    return
  }
  
}
```

in this example, overriding doThat method will cause a compile time error as the subclass will not be allowed to override this method, because it's private.

Comment: Looking over how I phrased the question originally, I don’t think I made it clear enough that I want the subclass to still be able to call the base function. I just don’t want anywhere outside the class hierarchy to be able to call the function. So private wouldn’t work because then the subclass can’t call it.

Comment: so, you want the class and its sub class only can call the function? in other languages you use protected instead of private. but in swift, private is enough because there is no way to be called out of the class hierarchy.

or you can use fileprivate but you have to make sure both the class and the subclasses  in written in the same file